# Spotify Intent in android?

Tags: android, intentfilter, spotify

I would like to play a certain spotify playlist, anyone knows if there is any Spotify intent filter available?

thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just an ordinary intent should work.

```
String spotifyUri = "spotify:user:...";
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(spotifyUri));
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I have tried this but apparently even when opening a url from the browser you only get the possibility to subscribe to a playlist and if you are already subscribed to the playlist nothing happens. With other words, playlists are no longer automatically opened and played. Has this recently changed maybe in the latest version(s)?